# Why $Result = 1 even when there is no error on database insert operation

Tags: sql, powershell

In below powershell script, I am trying to execute SQL insert statement within transaction and try/catch.

There is no errors and I am setting variable `$Result` with value `1` in catch block, still when I am seeing the value = 1 `Write-Host $Result`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string]$SQLServer='(local)'
)
# Database Update
Write-Host "Update Database" -ForegroundColor Green
& sqlcmd.exe -S $SQLServer -Q @"
USE [Test]
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO DBO.A1 (Name) VALUES ('test1')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;
    $($Result =1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
"@

Write-Host $Result
```

Comment: no, I also put the entire script, I haven't set anywhere.

Comment: As I tried to indicate on your previous question, what you're trying to do isn't going to work. What's happening? Well, powershell is running a string interpolation - it sees a string containing `$($Result = 1)` and effectively says, okay, let's evaluate *that*, and place the *result* of evaluating that into the string. Then that *resulting* string is what's passed to `sqlcmd.exe` for it to pass to SQL Server for execution. You *can't* get back into a powershell context from deep within a chunk of SQL code.

Comment: Also: `$result = 1` is basically - _"can I assign the value of one to the variable `$result`?"_ The answer is yes. Reminder: equality checking in PowerShell is `-eq`.

Comment: [Related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77298/how-to-make-sqlcmd-return-an-errorlevel-other-than-0-when-the-sql-script-fails). What do you expect `$($Result = 1)` to do? Hint: it does not assign a value of 1 to `$Result` when the transaction fails.

Comment: why does not assign a value of 1 to $Result when the transaction fails?

Comment: When do you think the subexpression (`$(...)`) inside the string is being evaluated?